# Weird Formatting Bug

Tags: bug, design, profile-page

Viewing the site on my Ipad with Safari, while viewing my profile or anyone's profile, it look really jumbled up here:

[image]

As you can see, all the different sections are all mixed up together like a salad. Can we fix this formatting issue?

Comment: I'm looking on an ipad, and I cannot reproduce this - it looks just fine here. Is it still doing it? What iOS version?